# Sort table row using javascript's array method- sort( ) & reverse( )

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, sorting

I want to put the table row in an array than use the loop to iterate the array for comparing two rows but i don't know how this sort method of array works is it going to compare from S.No column than initials column and so on.

how to use the array method to sort()- ascending order and descending order by reverse().
I don't want to use code from google want to make my own logic just help me where i am lacking.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .tab,
    .tab th,
    .tab tr,
    .tab td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      padding: 10px;

    }

    .circle {
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 50%;
      margin: 2px 22px 2px;
      line-height: 10px;
      padding: 12px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h2><u>CONTACT MANAGEMENT </u></h2></br></br>
  <form>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" style="text-transform: capitalize;" /> &nbsp;

    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" style="text-transform: capitalize;" /></br></br>

    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" pattern="[1-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" maxlength="10" /></br></br>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdn" value="1">
    <button type="button" onclick="dataSave()">save</button></br></br>
  </form>
  </br></br>
  <div class="div1">
    <table class="tab" id="table">
      <th>S.No</th>
      <th>Initals</th>
      <th>FullName</th>
      <th>PhoneNo.</th>
      <tbody id="table_row">
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <button type="button" id="asort_btn" class="sort" onclick="asec_sort()">Asec</button>
  <button type="button" id="dsort_btn" class="sort" onclick="desc_sort()">Desc</button>

  <script>
    function dataSave()
{

var first = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var last = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;

var firstNameArr = new Array();

var lastNameArr = new Array();

var phoneNoArr = new Array();

firstNameArr.push(first);
lastNameArr.push(last);
phoneNoArr.push(phone);

var num = parseInt(document.getElementById("hdn").value);

for(i=0;i<firstNameArr.length;i++)
{


var preFirstName = firstNameArr[i].slice(0,1);
var preLastName = lastNameArr[i].slice(0,1);

document.getElementById('table_row').innerHTML += `<tr><td>${num}</td>
<td class="circle">${preFirstName}${preLastName}</td>
<td>${firstNameArr[i]} ${lastNameArr[i]}</td>
<td>${phoneNoArr[i]}</td></tr>`;

}
 num = num+1;
 
 document.getElementById('hdn').value=num;
 document.getElementById('fname').value="";
 document.getElementById('lname').value="";
 document.getElementById('phone').value="";
 }

function asec_sort()
{
alert('hi');
var tableRowArr = new Array();
tableRowArr = document.getElementById('table_row').innerHTML;
console.log(tableRowArr);
console.log(tableRowArr.sort()); 

}

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you wanted to sort by the initials I see ?

Comment: pls don't use variable names like UpperCase_something. The convention is to use camelCase https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: @DennisQuan yes because full name is also sorted by the names so according to initials it will sort the row.